# Vertical Scrolling Effect in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, ads, smoothing

I stepped a little too far over my head in a job I took this week.

I need to develop a scrolling, changing background like the one on Chevy's home page: http://www.chevrolet.com/
Something like this might suffice though: wearethescenery.bigcartel.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have options: Silverlight, Flash, HTML5... pick a technology and let us know what you've tried and where you run into obstacles. The StackOverflow community is happy to help with programming questions, or even recommend a technology to achieve the desired effect. As stated, your question is ambiguous and it's hard to tell what sort of help you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plently of plugins available for jQuery to do just that:

- [25 jQuery Image Gallery/Slider Tutorials and Plugins](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/)
- [57+ Free Image Gallery, Slideshow And Lightbox Solutions/](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/)

Answer (score 0):

You could animate the background-position.

You need a large background image for that, which might slow down the page load.

If you are not against using a javascript library, [this jquery tutorial](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/) might help you solve your problem.